# Elasticsearch: Use loop in Painless script

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I have an old version of Elasticsearch (5.6.16) on a production environment that I can't upgrade.

I'm trying to use a loop in a painless `script_score` script but I always face a runtime error.

All my documents can have one or several "badges", here the mapping:

```
"myDocument":{
    "properties":{
        "badges":{
            "type":"nested",
            "properties":{
                "name":{
                    "type":"keyword"
                }
            }
        },
    }
},
```

My goal is to do a custom script that will provide a better score for documents with a specific type of badge

So I made this script

```
for (item in doc['badges']) {
    if (item['name'] == "myCustomBadge") {
        return _score * 10000;
    }
}
return _score;
```

But unfortunately, I'm getting errors while I try to use it

```
{
    "query":{
        "function_score":{
            "query":{
                "match_all": {}
            },
            "functions":[
                {
                    "script_score":{
                        "script":{
                            "inline":"for (item in doc['badges']) { if (item['name'] == \"myCustomBadge\") { return _score * 10000; }}return _score;",
                            "lang":"painless"
                        }
                    }
                },
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

```
    "error":{
        "root_cause":[
            {
                "type":"script_exception",
                "reason":"runtime error",
                "script_stack":[
                    "org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup.get(LeafDocLookup.java:77)",
                    "org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup.get(LeafDocLookup.java:36)",
                    "for (item in doc['badges']) { ",
                    " ^---- HERE"
                ],
                "script":"for (item in doc['badges']) { if (item['name'] == \"myCustomBadge\") { return _score * 10000; }}return _score;",
                "lang":"painless"
            }
        ],
        "type":"search_phase_execution_exception",
        "reason":"all shards failed"
    }
```

I tried to change the for with an other variant, but same error.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < doc['badges']; i++) {
        if (doc['badges'][i]['name'] == "uaWorker") {
            return _score * 10000;
        }
    }
    return _score;
```

Could you help me find what I did wrong?
Thanks you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the loop but the fact that `badges` is nested and you're trying to access it from doc values. In this case, you need to access the array of badges from the _source document directly, like this:

```
for (item in params._source['badges'])
```

Comment: Many thanks! I didn't know about that, I will look into it. I've tested it and everything is ok now :)